# Any XFree86 font close to the old redhat Luxi mono?

Tags: linux, debian, fonts, truetype

I'm on a Debian 6.0 system but miss the old fonts on those old red hat systems, the luxi mono, if I remember correctly. Are there any close variants in the free font family? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/) is *fairly* close, although Luxi is [still available](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/releases/individual/font/font-bh-ttf-1.0.3.tar.bz2) if it really matters.

Comment: Thanks! I tried DejaVu and I agree it is reasonably close, but still don't feel quite right. I like luxi mono simply because it reads like newspaper in the terminal, sound vague but that's what I am after...

Comment: ooos, apparently I can do with the nonfree package under Debian: "ttf-xfree86-nonfree".